# Regex to extract string between 2 strings (except if string = 'www')

Tags: regex

I have spent several hours looking for a solution to my regex issue but I can't seem to find a way to get it to work.

I have a list of URLs:

```
//dqsdq.dqsdqs
http://app.testing.co/
//niche.testing.co/
//niche.testing.co/dqsdqs
//niche.testing.co
//blaise.testing.com
//www.testing.co
//app.testing.co
//testing.co
```

What I'm trying to do is extract all the subdomains except empty subdomains, `www` and `app`.

Here is my regex so far

```
(?<=\/\/)(.*)(?=.testing.co)
```

https://regex101.com/r/SL3Es8/1

I can't figure out a way to exclude app and www. from group 1.

Comment: `(?<=\/\/(?!www\.|app\.)).*?(?=\.testing\.co(?=\/|$))`? See https://regex101.com/r/SL3Es8/2

Comment: `(?<=\/\/)(?!www|app)(.+)(?=\.testing.co)`